# JWT tokens in KMM

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin-multiplatform

I am stuck at how to implement JWT tokens at platform specific APIs, especially in swift side.

Here is my implementation so far:

```
expect fun getToken(): String
```

On Android side I have a library of JWT:

```
actual fun getToken(): String =
    Jwts.builder().setHeaderParam(JwsHeader.TYPE, JwsHeader.JWT_TYPE).claim("company", "ADO")
        .claim("session_token", "")
        .claim("api_token", "token").signWith(
            SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,
            Base64.encodeToString(
                "something".toByteArray(),
                Base64.DEFAULT
            )
        ).compact()
```

iOS Side:

```
actual fun getToken(): String {
    //TODO get the token from swift // --> what should implemented here?
    return ""
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what's the issue here. If you're using a library on Android then you would have to find either another library on iOS or do your own implementation. Also if the Android library is all Java code then you can easily port it into Kotlin and use it in `common` multiplatform layer to use from both android and ios.

Comment: thanks for the resonse . ccan you please explain about how to use aes encryption on common module

Comment: i have using Aes encryptionn on andorid using javaxx.ciphers class it is not useable in common module and also there is no library for aes encryption in ios

Comment: Would you please re-word the question along with content to ask about `AES Encryption` on KMM? I guess that's your pain point. That way it would be more clear and people would be able to answer if they're aware of a solution